# How to change first day of week (start day) Wednesday(User configurable), on the basis of week Start day & provided date get WeekNumber in Postgrace?

Tags: database, postgresql

while using DATE_PART('week', some_date) to get the date of the first day
of the week I noticed that it was working as expected: Monday is considered
the start of the week. But i want to change first day of week means week start day is Wednesaday. So how to set My week start day is wednesaday and on the basis of This week start day and Date that i provided, get the week number.
Below is the query that i ised to get week number.

```
select m.tool_id, m.module_location, alarm_count,  recipe_id, alarm_alias, alarm_issuer_name,
DATE_PART('week',alarm_date) AS week, 
DATE_PART('year',alarm_date) AS yearNo
from alarms.alarm_count a, alarms.alarm_module m, alarms.alarm_issuer ai 
where a.module_uuid = m.module_uuid and a.alarm_issuer_uuid = ai.alarm_issuer_uuid 
and m.module_uuid in (
'027909d4-12dd-4b7d-a391-847f88ee97ab',
 '212277f4-9d05-4465-95f7-a99fcb936451')
and (a.alarm_date) BETWEEN '2022-11-21' and '2022-12-05' 
and severity in ('Critical','Error','Fatal')
```

Answer (score 0):

`select DATE_PART('isodow', '20210104' :: date) AS Day` provides the day of the week as Monday (1) to Sunday (7)

`select translate(DATE_PART('isodow', '20210104' :: date) :: text,'1234567','6712345') AS Day` provides the day of the week as Wednesday(1) to Tuesday (7)

`select DATE_PART('week','20210104' :: date) AS Week` provides the number of the ISO 8601 week-numbering week of the year starting on Monday

`select DATE_PART('week','20210104' :: date) - translate(DATE_PART('isodow', '20210104' :: date) :: text,'1234567','1100000') :: double precision AS Week` provides the number of the ISO 8601 week-numbering week of the year starting on Wednesday.

However, on Monday and Tuesday of Week 1, this formula will return Week 0 instead of the last week of the previous year. So the right formula to get the week number is :

```
select CASE 
         WHEN DATE_PART('week','20210104' :: date) - translate(DATE_PART('isodow', '20210104' :: date) :: text,'1234567','1100000') :: double precision > 1
         THEN DATE_PART('week','20210104' :: date) - translate(DATE_PART('isodow', '20210104' :: date) :: text,'1234567','1100000') :: double precision
         ELSE DATE_PART('week','20210104' :: date - interval '2 days')
       END AS Week
```

And as a consequence, the formula to get the iso year is :

```
select CASE 
         WHEN DATE_PART('week','20210104' :: date) - translate(DATE_PART('isodow', '20210104' :: date) :: text,'1234567','1100000') :: double precision > 1
         THEN DATE_PART('isoyear','20210104' :: date)
         ELSE DATE_PART('isoyear','20210104' :: date - interval '2 days')
       END AS Year
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LQDeYXXn)

Comment: i want to make week first day is user configurable , so user provide the week start day and we pass this start day in my existing query that returns the week number (existing query return ISO compliant week number,day start from Monday(1) & End day Sunday(7)). week number i used in my java code to make group of weeks(ex: if start date is 21-11-2022 & end date 05-11-2022 & week start day WEDNESDAY then expected group of dates is 21-11-2022 to 22-11-2022, 23-11-2022 to 29-12-2022,30-11-2022 to 05-12-2022) . please suggest me what should i change in existing query

Comment: In your question, you don't talk about making first day of the the week as a user parameter, you just say 'Wednesday', and you don't group anything in your query. So please update your question to make it complete about what you want to achieve.

Comment: I dont want to group dates in query , i was just gining the example on the basis of week number i am getting the group of weeks in my java code. using DB query i just find out week number on the basis of user provided parameter like week start day, start date and end date. In my query i am just providing start date and end date as a parameter to find out weeknumber (as ISO compliant it takes Monday as first Day of week as default)